# c#, prime factors. В output не все цифры выводятся

Tags: c#

Выводятся не все цифры.Мне надо вот так: `Prime factors of 40 are: 2 x 2 x 2 x 5`, а выводится только `2 5`

```cs
using System;

namespace PrimeFactor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a  number greater than 1: ");
            
            int entry =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int num = entry;
            int testFactor = 1;
            string primeString = "";
            while (++testFactor <= num)
            {
                primeString += (num % testFactor == 0) ? " " + testFactor : "";
               

                while (num % testFactor == 0) num /= testFactor;

            }
            Console.WriteLine("The prime factors of " + entry + " are:" + primeString);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while (++testFactor <= num)
    {
      while (num % testFactor == 0) 
      {
        primeString += " " + testFactor;
        num /= testFactor;
      }
    }
```

```js
function primeFactors(num) {
  var testFactor = 1;
  var primeString = "";
  while (++testFactor <= num) {
    while (num % testFactor == 0) {
      primeString += " " + testFactor;
      num /= testFactor;
    }
  }
  return primeString;
}
console.log(primeFactors(40));
```

Comment: На мобиле выглядит просто как js код без примочек, я даже не понял сначала, зачем он здесь. напишите хоть пару строк пояснений, что где.